# Is it possible to change size of minimized window in MDI C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi, mdichild

Users complain that when they have several minimized windows in MDI container it's impossible to distinguish them unless they resore each. I wonder if it's possible to make minimized window a little bit wider so the text in the caption can contain 6 characters?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a workaround? Say is it possible to show a toolstrip when mouse hovers minimized form?

Comment: By "toolstrip", I assume you mean "tooltip"? And yes, that's an option, albeit not a very elegant one. Or you could teach them to use the "Window" menu, which lists (and allows switching to) all of the open windows with their full name.

Comment: I think you can use Windows menu as a workaround, which will help users to get all the child windows. - Set MDIWindowListItem property of the menustrip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.** Windows determines the width of a minimized window using the current system parameters, and there's no way to change this dynamically for a single application without changing the values across the entire system.

Specifically, the default size of all minimized windows is 160x31. In a MDI application, you actually get to see this size because the window is minimized into its MDI host, rather than into the Windows taskbar. Raymond Chen (a developer on the Windows Shell team at Microsoft) published a couple of blog entries a while back that explain why this particular size was chosen, and what it means. The first is available here: [Why do minimized windows have an apparent size of 160x31?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/10/370445.aspx) And the second follow-up entry can be read here: [No, really, why is it 160x31?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/07/659013.aspx) As he explains in that second post:

> The width of the miniature title bar is determined by the `iWidth` member of `MINIMIZEDMETRICS` structure. You can retrieve and change this structure with the help of the `SystemParametersInfo` function. (Use the `SPI_GETMINIMIZEDMETRICS` and `SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS` flags, respectively.) Some people will mention the `MinWidth` registry value, but those people are wrong. Notice, for example, that messing with `MinWidth` requires a logoff cycle, whereas using `SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS` takes effect immediately. That's because `SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS` updates the internal state variables, whereas whacking the registry just change a value in a database that nobody pays attention to once you've logged on.
>
> What about the height? That's just the height of a caption bar, which you can adjust from the Appearance tab of the Display control panel. (Programmatically, you can use that helpful `SystemParametersInfo` function, this time using the `iCaptionHeight` member of the `NONCLIENTMETRICS` structure.)

Since I doubt your users really want you messing with their default system parameters by P/Invoking the [`SystemParametersInfo` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx), you aren't left with a whole lot of options. My recommendation, especially if they're working with a single window at a time and leaving the others minimized, is to switch to an alternative interface. The intention of MDI was to allow users to tile or cascade multiple windows so that they could see more than one at a time. Since it sounds like that's not the typical use case, you might both be better served by switching the application to use tabs instead. This is often called a **tabbed document interface (TDI)**, a somewhat more modern implementation of the old multiple document interface (MDI). It's become quite popular over the years; check out the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(GUI)).

Answer (score 0):

[Although this post is 11 years old, i'm trying...:
I'm facing an issue with in-app minimized windows, which are broken on my Windows11 (certainly by a software, but I don't know which one...). Those in-app minimized windows are much more narrower that it should be. Instead of having the minimized title bar containing title and 3 buttons, I can only see the close button. You said here it wasn't possible to change this size for a unique software, but I assume you know(knew) where to change it for the whole system? Here is a capture of the issue in ultraedit [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQAyU.jpg) and here in 3dsMax for example [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmRco.jpg)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31028674)

Answer (score 0):

To those who have the same problem as me, I found the solution:

(win+r) regedit
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
add the string value "MinWidth".

Change the string value named "MinWidth". Set its value using the following formula:
-15*width in pixels

For me, acceptable one was -3300

Little drawback: It also changes size of the minimized windows in the taskbar (make them much wider when there is a few of them in taskbar)

Comment: This does not solve the problem. You should not assume the user to change their windows registry setting for just this specific case.