# Arranging minimised child windows on MDI

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have an MDI program with multiple child windows. Is there any way I can influence or modify the way that `LayoutMdi( MdiLayout.ArrangeIcons)` arranges minimised child windows in the form, or is there any way I can change the position and/or size of minimised child windows (eg in the same kind of way that I can change the position and size of the unminimised child windows using `SetBounds`)

Comment: You are dived deep to a narrow sea. Come out and rethink about implementation of your business logic.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813637/is-it-possible-to-change-size-of-minimized-window-in-mdi-c-sharp-winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d6014e48-2adb-4096-8bea-94c2f3b1c47c/how-to-change-the-location-of-a-minimized-mdichild-form?forum=winforms

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    public FormA() {
        Button btn = new Button { Text = "asdf" };
        Controls.Add(btn);
        IsMdiContainer = true;
        var f1 = new Form { Text = "Form1", TopLevel = false, MdiParent = this};
        var f2 = new Form { Text = "Form2", TopLevel = false, MdiParent = this};
        var f3 = new Form { Text = "Form3", TopLevel = false, MdiParent = this};
        f1.Show();
        f2.Show();
        f3.Show();
        btn.Click += delegate {
            //this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.ArrangeIcons);
            //f1.Bounds = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 30);
             int top = 100;
             SetWindowPos(f1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, f1.Left, top, f1.Width, f1.Height, 0);
        };
   }
```