# How to change the size of a minimized MDI window in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, size, mdi, minimized

I'm facing an issue with in-app minimized windows, which are broken on my Windows 11 (certainly by a software, but I don't know which one...). Those in-app minimized windows are much more narrower that it should be. Instead of having the minimized title bar containing title and 3 buttons, I can only see the close button. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813637/is-it-possible-to-change-size-of-minimized-window-in-mdi-c-sharp-winforms/71051053?noredirect=1#comment125685827_71051053) it wasn't possible to change this size for a unique software, but I assume it's possible to change it for the whole system? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQAyU.jpg) is a capture of the issue in ultraedit and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmRco.jpg) in 3dsMax for example.

Comment: Same problem. Not sure why this is down voted. the default size of all minimized windows is SUPPOSED to be 160x31 - apparently they changed something for windows 11

Comment: To those who have the same problem as me, I found the solution:

(win+r) regedit HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics add the string value "MinWidth".

Change the string value named "MinWidth". Set its value using the following formula: -15*width in pixels

For me, acceptable one was -3300

Little drawback: It also changes size of the minimized windows in the taskbar (make them much wider when there is a few of them in taskbar)

Comment: This is a good work around. I've made another post about this which I thought may describe the issue more clearly, if you want to answer it with this solution that'd be fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531701/winforms-mdi-has-new-minimum-child-size-in-windows-11