# winforms MDI has new minimum child size in windows 11?

Tags: winforms, minimize, mdichild, mdiparent, windows-11

Supposedly, the default size of all minimized windows is 160x31 but this has been changed in windows 11?

[image]

Is there yet another registry change or other work around that can revert this back to windows 10 functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(win+r) regedit HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics add the string value "MinWidth".

Change the string value named "MinWidth". Set its value using the following formula: -15*width in pixels

For me, acceptable one was -3300

Little drawback: It also changes size of the minimized windows in the taskbar (make them much wider when there is a few of them in taskbar)